# Change UIScrollView Content size

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, contentsize

I have ViewController with UIScrollView, some UIImages and UIButtons.
In the Storyboard I set the size of UIScrollView to: width: 320, height: 570

I want to change Contentsize of my UIScrollView when the ViewController was loaded.

I added side in the viewDidLoad:

```
        scrlMain.contentSize = CGSize(width: 320,height: 790)
```

And also I added code in the viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
        self.scrlMain.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

But my UIScrollView is still the last size = 570.
I can't use viewDidAppear because, when I press the button, it need it to change color. When it has changed color, my UIScrollView moves to up.

What did I do wrong?

All code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrlMain.delegate = self
    scrlMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 790)
    }
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.scrlMain.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    self.scrlMain.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrlMain.frame.width, height: 60.0 + 5 * (self.scrlMain.frame.width / 16.0 * 5.0));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there was an error in the this function:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
self.scrlMain.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
self.scrlMain.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrlMain.frame.width, height: 60.0 + 5 * (self.scrlMain.frame.width / 16.0 * 5.0));
}
```

I delete this code:

```
self.scrlMain.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrlMain.frame.width, height: 60.0 + 5 * (self.scrlMain.frame.width / 16.0 * 5.0));
```

And all was right

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Dim you can try this-

```
yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 568)
```

And you can change size 568 to whatever you want.

Comment: Hey @Mohd, I tried added scrlMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 790) and in the viewDidLoad. But I have the same problem.

Comment: For me not. I move UIScrollView to down, but it does not fix. It moves back. If add this code in viewDidAppear, UIScrollView can fix. But I can't use viewDidAppear.

Comment: Can you share your screen using <Skype or TeamViewer>

Comment: Yes, I can. How I can do it?

Comment: I wrote you in the Skype. If you didn't get my request, write me your login please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES
```

and you please maintain the difference between your screen size and your scrollview content size... so that it can be visible properly

suppose yourScrollViewSize greatertThan yourScreenSize

Comment: I added code: scrlMain.userInteractionEnabled = true; in the viewDidLoad. But I have the same problem. In the Storyboard ViewController has 570, UIScrollController has 570.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width:0, height:self.scrollview.frame.height*2) // whatever hight you want
    }
}
```

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews is always called on the main thread - passing this work to the main thread from the main thread is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to change the content size from within the page without running ViewDidLoad again.

Just add

```
scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

after you set the new contentSize

Example when you change the content size (*viewImages*) within the UIscrollView (*scrollViewImages*)

```
viewImages.frame.size = CGSize(width: width, height: 128)
viewImages.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
viewImages.setNeedsLayout()
scrollViewImages.setNeedsLayout()
scrollViewImages.layoutIfNeeded()
```